# How would you write the name and aspiring title for someone in an enterprise environmemnt?

Tags: honorifics

How would you write the following (name, aspiring title) pair in a company context:

> ```
> John Smith, to be Specialist
> ```

"To be" here is meant in the sense of TBD (to be defined or to be done) or TBC (to be confirmed), etc.

Would it be more correct to use one of the following:

1. ---, to be assigned Specialist
2. ---, candidate for Specialist
3. ---, to be assigned the Specialist grade

or another form?

Comment: So John is confirmed a job at the company, but he hasn't started working yet?

Comment: *John Smith, aspiring Specialist* tells you that he's an aspiring Specialist.

Comment: @Jazzachi, the current title is Senior Consultant/Engineer. This is in the context of a promotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you use in the question is appropriate

> John Smith, an aspiring Specialist

or

> John Smith, Specialist applicant  / John Smith, applicant for the role of specialist.

(both make sense only if 'Specialist' is used as a title, I assume it is because you've capitalised it